# Expandable Item in List on Android

Tags: listview, android, listitem

I'm trying to make a list item expandable.  Basically, I want to have a button on each list item that, when pushed, expands that list item to show more info.

Is this possible on android?  if so, how would i do it?

Thanks

Edit:  To clarify, ideally I'd like the current list item to enlargen to show more info

Comment: You could have a look at [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your easiest solution would probably be an [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

But you can also implement something yourself where a button in each `ListView` item unhides and hides `View` under the normal item.

Comment: Hiding/unhiding works the best here, do you know of any easy to animate the expansion of the list item?  So the view slowly expands downward instead of just suddenly being larger?

Comment: unfortunately no.  i created my own expandable list view that simply hid/unhid and that worked for me, but i'm guessing you could try a SlidingDrawer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html  but i'm not sure if this would fit your application.  sorry i couldn't be more of help!

Answer (score 1):

You use the API-Demo for help.
There is a really good example of ExpandableListViews

Here the [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List6.html)

Comment: As a general rule it's better to type out a full answer in SO, rather than just link to a tutorial, to prevent link rot. In this case, I've just clicked on the link, but it's no longer active / correct :(